# Why store session data in an application database?

Tags: php, mysql, database, session, membership

Unless it has to do specifically with the application, why keep track of the session in a database?  I mean, most session data has to do with users with membership, so if the user is logged in, you can easily keep track of them via their member id. So why keep session data in the database?

Comment: what if the same credentials appear from two sources?

Comment: if it a large amount of data maybe?

Comment: Two main reasons: one, multiple web servers can access the session data. Two, as concurrent users increase, the db becomes much faster than using flat files.

Comment: ohhh so you guys are saying if the same user is logged in different browsers or more than one person is logged in as the same user.  I see, that does make sense to store session data.  But any deeper techinical reasons?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not everyone runs with just a single server, and file-based sessions are difficult to share between multiple servers reliably. Putting the session into a database takes care of most of those sharing problems.

Comment: but lets say we only want to keep track of users that are logged in, then there's no reason to keep track of session data right?

Comment: And how do you tell that a user's logged in? Can't do it via cookies, because then it'd be simple for a malicious user to forge a 'logged in' cookie and run amok in your system. That's why there's sessions - to keep sensitive data, like login status, out of the hands of users.